# how to transforme an excel formula into a VBA cdoe

Tags: vba, excel

I want to transforme this excel formula into a VBA code

```
For i = 1 To table1Rows
table1(i + 1, 28)
table1(2, 28)= SI(W2="OK";GAUCHE(A2&"";12)&";"&B2& ";"&AN2& ";"&Q2& ";"&GAUCHE(D2&" ";20)&";"&TEXTE(C2;"JJ/MM/AAAA")&";"&DROITE(""&TEXTE(AX2;"0,000000");16)&";"&DROITE(""&TEXTE(AP2;"0,00");12)&";"&DROITE(""&TEXTE(AR2;"0,00");12)&";"&DROITE(""&TEXTE(AT2;"0,00");12)&";"&AU2& ";"&AV2& ";";"")
```

Comment: what even is the above?? please present in clearer format so we can assist you. Thanks

Comment: it's too long :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select the cell with the formula in Excel.
2. Run the code:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

       Dim strFormula  As String
       Dim strParenth  As String

       strParenth = """"

       strFormula = Selection.FormulaLocal
       strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

       strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
       Debug.Print strFormula

   End Sub
   ```
3. See the immediate window.
4. Send me a virtual beer.

Comment: I don't know where I can insert this code, could you explain me please. I wil send you a pack of Heinken :)

Comment: @YassineZagliz - simply create a new module in VBA and paste it there.

Comment: Where can I paste the formula in the code that you proposed?

Comment: @YassineZagliz - Do not paste the formula. Select the formula, as it is in Excel. Run the code. See the immediate window. The new formula is there.

Comment: the problem is that I already have a macro for the same sheet, :(

Comment: @YassineZagliz - add a new module. Paste my code there. Select the formula in the Excel cell. Run the code.

Comment: Thank you so much!